# Python string to formatted text in Apple Notes?

Tags: python, applescript, richtext

I've written a Python script to extract notes and highlights from my kindle. Now I would like to create a formatted string that I can write from Python to my clipboard, and then ideally paste into Apple Notes with formatting (headers, font style, etc.). I've looked around by can't really find anything on this. Is this possible? I'm open to using additional tools (shortcuts, applescript, etc.) if absolutely necessary, but my preference would be to have a self-contained python script.

Comment: You might do a search for notes and applescript. Generally, formatting in Notes is html. There are some posts here (or on ask different) that show how to work with it to a limited extent. At the very least, it would be easy to format a note the way you want and then get the 'body' of it and see how it looks under the hood. Then you could probably do something in python that matched.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @mockman, I wasn't able to find a solution where I could copy the formatted note to my clipboard, but I was able to create a working solution using your solution. Steps:

1. Format a note manually how you would like it to be.
2. Using applescript, extract the body of the text. This contains the html formatting required to reproduce your formatted note.

   ```
    tell Application "Notes"
        activate
        tell account "iCloud"
             get body of note "Title of Note"
        end tell 
    end tell
   ```
3. Use this HTML as a template to create new applescript. It will be used
   in the body attribute of the following applescript code.

   ```
    tell Application "Notes"
        activate
        tell account "iCloud"
             make new note at folder "Notes" with properties {body:"custom_html_goes_here"}
        end tell 
    end tell
   ```
4. Have python automatically populate applescript text for you using the html template you created.
5. Run applescript from python by calling `subprocess.run`. I've created a custom function for this (below):

   ```
    def run_applescript(cmd):
        result = subprocess.run(['osascript', '-e', cmd], capture_output=True)
        return result
   ```
6. The full python code is shared below. It reads in a json file, populates applescript compatible text based on the template html, and then runs an applescript subprocess which generates a new formatted note in the default "Notes" folder.

   ```
   import subprocess
   import json

   def run_applescript(cmd):
       result = subprocess.run(['osascript', '-e', cmd], capture_output=True)
       return result

   body = '''tell application "Notes"
       activate
       tell account "iCloud"
           make new note at folder "Notes" with properties {{body:"{}"}}
       end tell
   end tell'''

   title_template = r'<div><b><span style=\"font-size: 24px\">{}</span></b></div>'
   author_template = r"<div><b>By: {}</b></div>"
   chapter_template = r'<div><b><font color=\"#31B6E6\"><span style=\"font-size: 18px\">{}</span></font></b><br></div>'
   location_template = r'<div><b><i><font color=\"#7531A9\">{}</font></i></b><br></div>'
   blank_line =  "<div><br></div>"

   with open('output.json') as f:
      d = json.load(f)

   text = title_template.format(d.pop('title'))
   text += author_template.format(d.pop('author')) + blank_line

   for chapter, lst in d.items():
       text += chapter_template.format(f'{chapter}:')
       for item in lst:
           text  += location_template.format(f"{item['Type']}: {item['Location']}")
           text += f"{item['noteText']}" 
           text += blank_line

   cmd = body.format(text)
   out = run_applescript(cmd.encode()
   ```

An example of a formatted note is shown below.
[image: Example formatted note]